# Changing theme language in Liferay Shows a pop-Up

Tags: liferay-7

I'm changing the liferay theme language from the portlet. I'm able to successfully do that but after changing the Language there a pop-up appears asking whether I really want to change the default language. I want to remove it anyone having some Idea.
[you can see the image of popup when I change language to Japan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vLgj.png)

Comment: Please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and please include a [minimal, verifyable and complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This popup is just telling you that you selected a different language than your default. Setting this language as yours should make the popup dissapear. I think for guest users there is no popup